# Error trying to get the name of the client PC. Unknown Host Error. In asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, websocket, server, dns

how is it, I happen to have a problem in my production site, that when I publish my code, I get the following error:

**System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Unknown host**
**SocketException (0x2af9)**

The reason is because I am trying to get the name of the pc on a client computer. When I try with the following codes, the problem is the same:

```
String Hostname =  System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.ServerVariables["remote_addr"]).HostName.Split(new Char[] { '.' });
String nombrePC = Hostname;
```

or with:

```
String PCname = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry (Request.ServerVariables ["remote_addr"]). HostName
```

In my localhost development team, I have no problem, but when I navigate to the production site, that's what happens.

If anyone has any ideas, I would greatly appreciate it. I do not know what would be better, configure the server, or change the line of code to get the name of the computer. I preferred to do the correction from the code

Comment: Probably "remote_addr" is a local IP or a router/proxy may have even removed the header. Check the content of "remote_addr" on your production site.

Comment: Also, you will not be able to retrieve the host name of an user computer.

Comment: And how or where could I review it?

Comment: Show it on the response...

Comment: Do you mean that the value remote_addr shows it in a variable to see what it brings?

Another thing, I've also tried it with this, but it's the same error when loading the page.
System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry (Request.UserHostAddress) .HostName